# Exception on web api asp.net mvc6 app that i did not registered a service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a asp.net MVC6 project and I am having some troubles on my web api. When I test a certain Api i get internal error (500 http response code).

I investigated and I found this error, which says that i haven't registered the object i am trying to get from services:

> No service for type
> 'DotnetProject.BusinessLayer.Implementation.QueryHandlers.GetTestByIdQueryHandler'
> has been registered.

The problem is that my controller requests a certain object from IoC container with `[FromServices]` syntax and i get a exception that i didn't register that service even tough i did.

If I don't request that object from services I don't get internal error anymore.

I get that error for all api functions that request a object with `[FromServices]` syntax.  So the problem is somewhere there but i can't figure it out.

Here is my controller class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DotnetProject.BusinessLayer.Interfaces;
using DotnetProject.DataLayer.Domain_Entities;
using DotnetProject.DataLayer.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using DotnetProject.BusinessLayer.Implementation.Queries.Users;
using DotnetProject.BusinessLayer.Implementation.QueryHandlers.Users;
using DotnetProject.BusinessLayer.Implementation.QueryResults.Users;
using DotnetProject.BusinessLayer.Implementation.Queries;
using DotnetProject.BusinessLayer.Implementation.QueryHandlers;
using DotnetProject.BusinessLayer.Implementation.Commands.Users;
using DotnetProject.BusinessLayer.Implementation.CommandHandlers.Users;
using DotnetProject.BusinessLayer.Implementation.Commands;
using DotnetProject.BusinessLayer.Implementation.CommandHandlers;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace DotnetProject.Controllers.Api
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {

        private ITestRepository testRepository;
        private ITestService testService;

        public TestController(ITestRepository _testRepository,ITestService _testService)
        {
            testRepository = _testRepository;
            testService = _testService;
        }

        // GET: api/values
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getAllTests")]
        public GetAllTestsQueryResult GetAll([FromServices] GetAllTestsQueryHandler handler)
        {
            return handler.Retrieve(new GetAllTestsQuery());

        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getTest")]
        public GetTestByIdQueryResult GetTest([FromServices]GetTestByIdQueryHandler handler,GetTestByIdQuery query)
        {
            return handler.Retrieve(query);   
        }


        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("delete")]
        public void Delete(DeleteTestCommand command,[FromServices]DeleteTestHandler handler)
        {
            handler.Execute(command);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("add")]
        public void AddTest(AddTestCommand command, [FromServices]AddTestHandler handler) {
            handler.Execute(command);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("update")]
        public void UpdateTest(UpdateTestCommand command,[FromServices]UpdateTestHandler handler) {

            handler.Execute(command);
        }
    }


}
```

Here is a object example that is found as "not registered":

```
using AT.Core.Cqrs;
using DotnetProject.BusinessLayer.Implementation.Commands.Users;
using DotnetProject.DataLayer;
using DotnetProject.DataLayer.Domain_Entities;
using DotnetProject.DataLayer.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DotnetProject.BusinessLayer.Implementation.CommandHandlers.Users
{
    public class AddTestHandler : ICommandHandler<AddTestCommand>
    {
        private ITestRepository _testRepository;

        public AddTestHandler(ITestRepository testRepository)
        {
            _testRepository = testRepository;
        }

        public void Execute(AddTestCommand newTest)
        {
            Test test = new Test();
            test.Id = newTest.Id;
            test.QuestionList = newTest.QuestionList;
            test.TestDuration = newTest.TestDuration;
            _testRepository.Add(test);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my ConfigureServices function from Startup file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());
    });
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
    services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
    services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<ITestRepository, TestRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<ITestService, TestService>();
    services.AddScoped<IRoleService, RoleService>();
    services.AddScoped<IRoleRepository, RoleRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler<DeleteUserCommand>, DeleteUserHandler>();
    services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler<UpdateUserCommand>,UpdateUserHandler>();
    services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler<AddUserCommand>, AddUserHandler>();
    services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler<DeleteTestCommand>, DeleteTestHandler>();
    services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler<UpdateTestCommand>, UpdateTestHandler>();
    services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler<AddTestCommand>, AddTestHandler>();
    services.AddScoped<IQueryHandler<GetAllTestsQuery,GetAllTestsQueryResult>,GetAllTestsQueryHandler>();
    services.AddScoped<IQueryHandler<GetTestByIdQuery, GetTestByIdQueryResult>,GetTestByIdQueryHandler>();
    services.AddScoped<IQueryHandler<GetAllUsersQuery, GetAllUsersQueryResult>, GetAllUsersQueryHandler>();
    services.AddScoped<IQueryHandler<GetUserByIdQuery, GetUserByIdQueryResult>, GetUserByIdQueryHandler>();

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>();
    services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        config.OutputFormatters.Clear();
        config.OutputFormatters.Add(new JsonOutputFormatter(new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
        }, ArrayPool<char>.Shared));
    });

    services.AddMvc();
    
    // Inject an implementation of ISwaggerProvider with defaulted settings applied
    services.AddSwaggerGen();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `ConfigureServices` in the example, `GetTestByIdQueryHandler was not registered`. An interface `IQueryHandler<GetTestByIdQuery, GetTestByIdQueryResult>` was registered, that when encountered would resolve to `GetTestByIdQueryHandler`. There is a difference and it is easily misunderstood.

The DI container is unaware of what to do when asked to resolve `GetTestByIdQueryHandler` directly.

So either update services to

```
services.AddScoped<GetTestByIdQueryHandler, GetTestByIdQueryHandler>();
```

so that it knows how to handle `GetTestByIdQueryHandler`

OR

update the actions to call the type that the DI container is aware of.

```
// GET api/values/5
[HttpGet]
[Route("getTest")]
public GetTestByIdQueryResult GetTest([FromServices]IQueryHandler<GetTestByIdQuery, GetTestByIdQueryResult> handler,GetTestByIdQuery query)
{
    return handler.Retrieve(query);   
}
```

Ideally the interfaces should follow some convention.

```
public interface IGetTestByIdQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<GetTestByIdQuery, GetTestByIdQueryResult> {

}

public class GetTestByIdQueryHandler : IGetTestByIdQueryHandler {
    //...
}
```

Registered accordingly

```
services.AddScoped<IGetTestByIdQueryHandler, GetTestByIdQueryHandler>();
```

And resolved cleanly

```
// GET api/test/getTest
[HttpGet]
[Route("getTest")]
public GetTestByIdQueryResult GetTest([FromServices]IGetTestByIdQueryHandler handler, GetTestByIdQuery query) {
    return handler.Retrieve(query);   
}
```

Comment: Hi Nkosi. Thanks for the answer! Adding this ->services.AddScoped<IGetTestByIdQueryHandler, GetTestByIdQueryHandler>();<- did the trick .